# How to slice list with objects from dictionary and transfer to template?

Tags: python, dictionary, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have dict with model and two div`s in template.

views.py

```
args['projects'] = Projects.objects.all()  
args['step'] = Projects.objects.all()[1::3]
```

html

```
{% if projects.id != step.id %}
    {% for item in projects %}
        <div class="smallblog" style="background-image: url({{ item.img.url }});">
            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ item.text|safe }}</p>
            <a href="/projects/{{ item.slug }}">Подробнее</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% elif projects.id == step.id %}
    {% for obj in step %}
        <div  class="bigblog" style="background-image: url({{ obj.img.url }});">
            <h3>{{ obj.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ obj.text|safe }}</p>
            <a href="/projects/{{ obj.slug }}">Подробнее</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Sorry, I do not speak English well. I want to bring the blocks, one block is small, one block is big. There is a list of projects in the same row three objects, the central objects are big blocks, the other small. Gets an object 2, 5, 8, 11 and so on are big blocks and the other small. But, unfortunately, it takes only small blocks.

Comment: What behavior are you observing, and what behavior did you expect?

Comment: Do you have a question? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The context variables `step` and `projects` are querysets. What do you expect `projects.id` or `step.id` to return?